# Custom date attribute in magento frontend displays 01.01.70 if no value

Tags: magento, date, attributes

I am stuck with a date-issue in Magento v. 1.7 i hope someone can help me with:

I have a custsom date attribute 'ExpiringDate' that I show in front end. This attribute is connected to my attribute set 'Food', and not to my other attribute set 'NonFood'. My products in the Food attribute set might have a date, or they don't.

The code `<?php echo $_product->getExpiringDate() ?>` gives me the result 2013-07-15 00:00:00 for food products with date. And blank result for products without date and/or the NonFood products (the blank result is preferred, but not the zeros).

The code `<?php echo date("d.m.y", strtotime($_product->getExpiringDate())) ?>` gives me the better formated result 15.07.13 for food products with date, but displays 01.01.70 for all other products.

So how can I either get the first code to show 15.07.13 or 15.07.2013 - but without the trailing 00:00:00

..or get the second code to not display anything if there is no value.

Thanks!

-Espen

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to this, for example like this:

```
<?php if ($_product->getExpiringDate() != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'): ?>
    <?php echo date("d.m.y", strtotime($_product->getExpiringDate())) ?>     
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I had to remove 0000-00-00 00:00:00 from the code above, and it worked perfectly. Thank you Jürgen! :)